# Error in loadNamespace when trying to use R package magick

Tags: r, namespaces, install.packages

I wanted to install the R package magick, don´t get an error when doing so, but then when I type library(´magick´) I get

> Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
>     namespace 'Rcpp' 0.12.10 is already loaded, but >= 0.12.12 is required
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for 'magick'

Any advice on this? I did update R to the latest version! Do I somehow have to de and reinstall Rcpp? Just install.packages('Rcpp') did not do the trick, neither:(

Thanks! Kat

Comment: update your Rcpp package. `install.packages("Rcpp", dependencies = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the error message, you need a more recent version of Rcpp : 
'**Rcpp' 0.12.10 is already loaded, but >= 0.12.12 is required** Error: package or namespace load failed for 'magick'

Try updating Rcpp by updating your whole library `update.packages(ask = FALSE)` or `install.packages("Rcpp")`